# Print Number of Outlier Readings Into a List

Tags: python, list

I am attempting to print out the number of outlier readings into a list but it is returning this output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here is my code for this function. It seems like it is in a loop until the number of outlier readings counted is finished, and I would like it to print only the final value for each key. NOTE: I must keep this function in my code

```
def calculateOutlierReadings():
    for option in options_readings:
        readings = options_readings[option]
        count = 1
        for row in readings:
            if(row > 180 or row <0):
                outlier_readings.append(count)
                count +=1
```

Here is some sample input that may help test this code.

```
 [96.0, 65.0, 26.0, 37.0, 175.0, 15.0, 121.0, 88.0, 117.0, 179.0, 119.0, 20.0, 84.0, 14.0, 22.0, 79.0, 152.0, 68.0, 81.0, 81.0, 136.0, 78.0, 22.0, 50.0, 8.0, 33.0, 83.0, 199.0, 18.0, 57.0, 114.0, 64.0, 68.0, 157.0, 11.0, 68.0, 47.0, 53.0, 69.0, 85.0, 24.0, 146.0, 123.0, 175.0, 7.0, 48.0, 22.0, 140.0, 12.0, 50.0, 16.0, 155.0, 142.0, 47.0, 14.0, 125.0, 84.0, 52.0, 178.0, 162.0, 141.0, 160.0, 176.0, 118.0, 87.0,  149.0, 145.0, 93.0, 154.0, 36.0, 161.0, 101.0, 77.0, 171.0, 11.0, 106.0, 157.0, 158.0, 154.0, 79.0, 131.0, 30.0, 26.0, 149.0, 25.0, 35.0, 79.0, 38.0, 17.0, 120.0, 126.0, 171.0, 141.0, 154.0, 158.0, 80.0, 99.0, 1.0, 22.0, 22.0, 176.0, 131.0, 167.0, 94.0, 32.0, 64.0, -5.0]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please give us a sample input so that it is reproducible.

Comment: will edit the post and copy and paste the output and some input for this example, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your append outside of the loop so that you can only append once the loop has completed.

You should count for every `row` that qualifies in `readings` and then append one time per `option` in `options_readings`.

```py
def calculateOutlierReadings():
    for option in options_readings:
        readings = options_readings[option]
        count = 1
        for row in readings:
            if(row > 180 or row <0):
                count +=1
        outlier_readings.append(count)  # move this
```

Comment: This worked and printed out perfectly, thank you as I was unsure of where it was looping incorrectly.

Comment: No problem. Please checkmark the answer and vote if your question is solved. My advice in the future is to take a small example and print what is happening at every level to help you figure out what is looping when and where you are going wrong.